# Gridbaglayout problem with layout (java swing)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Good day everyone, as I'm a beginner with java programming id like to ask some experienced coders here. so I am trying to make an inventory system but there is a problem with my layout [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04wx2.png) The "Annual balance" panel must be below the "Record of sales" panel then the "Record of sales" panel must fill the space above horizontally. Anyone have an idea on what is the problem.

```
public MainViewForm(String text)
{



       setTitle("Computer Warehouse ni SeQuoia");  
       setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
       setSize(1200,900);        
       setResizable(true);
       setVisible(true);



       mBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(mBar);

       mFile = new JMenu("FILE");
    mBar.add(mFile);

    mEdit = new JMenu("EDIT");
    mBar.add(mEdit);

    mView = new JMenu("VIEW");
    mBar.add(mView);

    mSave = new JMenu("SAVE");
    mBar.add(mSave);

    tBSave = new JToggleButton("SAVE");
    mSave.add(tBSave);

    mHelp = new JMenu("HELP");
    mBar.add(mHelp);

     mOption = new JMenu("OPTION");
     mBar.add(mOption);

     mEnd = new JMenu("END");
     mBar.add(mEnd);

     tbExit = new JToggleButton("EXIT");
     mEnd.add(tbExit);


   dlyForm = new DailyForm();
   mtlyForm = new MonthlyForm();
   tForm = new TableForm();
   abForm = new AnnualBalanceForm();

   GridBagConstraints gbc_dlyForm = new GridBagConstraints();
   gbc_dlyForm.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
   gbc_dlyForm.weightx=1;
   gbc_dlyForm.weighty=1;
   gbc_dlyForm.gridx=0;
   gbc_dlyForm.gridy=0;
   add(dlyForm,gbc_dlyForm );

   GridBagConstraints gbc_mtlyForm = new GridBagConstraints();
   gbc_mtlyForm.weightx=1;
   gbc_mtlyForm.weighty=1;
   gbc_mtlyForm.gridx=0;
   gbc_mtlyForm.gridy=0;
   gbc_mtlyForm.insets=new Insets(225,0,0,0);
   gbc_mtlyForm.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
   add(mtlyForm,gbc_mtlyForm);

   GridBagConstraints gbc_tForm = new GridBagConstraints();
   gbc_tForm.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
   gbc_tForm.weightx=0.1;
   gbc_tForm.weighty=0.1;
   gbc_tForm.anchor= GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
   add(tForm,gbc_tForm);

   GridBagConstraints gbc_abForm = new GridBagConstraints();
   gbc_abForm.anchor= GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
   gbc_abForm.weightx=1;
   gbc_abForm.weighty=1;

   add(abForm,gbc_abForm);

   pack();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified `gridx`/`gridy` for those constraints. They default to `RELATIVE`, so the next component moves over on both the horizontal and vertical.

(If there's one thing I'd most like to change about your code, it's the naming. I don't care about the type (in the name), so remove that and don't abbreviate the remaining useful words. Also worth noting the the `GridBagConstraints` data gets copied, so you can reuse them where appropriate.)

Comment: So for example in my first button i used gridbagconstraint of gridx=0 , i dont have to call gridx=0 again on the next line. i just have to use it when its already appropriate?

Comment: @SeQuoia Yeah. (So long as you use the same `GridBagConstraints` instance, obviously.)